# Can't find role when adding user to role in Asp.Net API Controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

So, just when I finally thought I had understood the Microsoft Asp.Net Identity Role System ... I run into a new problem...

I have a working controller that does my role management but I had problems in the view so I decided to use angularjs for my Web-Apps Admin-Panel.

Everything seemed to work after a bit of hacking but now I'm at a point that I don't understand at all. My process:

- Admin presses a button, which passes a user ID (string) to an angular Controller.
- Angular makes a POST Request to my ApiController, passing the userID to a Controller action that is supposed to authorize my user.

Here is my API Controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> changeAuth()
    {
        string userID;
        var requestData = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(requestData))
        {
            userID = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Models.ApplicationUser user;
        try
        {
            user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userID);
            if (user == null)
                throw(new Exception());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("couldn't find user in db");
        }
            foreach(var role in user.Roles)
            {
                testlist.Add(RoleManager.FindById(role.RoleId).Name);
            }
            if (!IsUserInRole(user, authRole))
            {
                IdentityResult res = new IdentityResult();
                try
                {
                    res = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, authRole.Id);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ex);
                }
            }
            if(IsUserInRole(user, authRole)
                return Ok("User is now authorized!");
            else
                return InternalServerError("Adding User to Role failed");
    }
```

- I load the userID (which works)
- I load the user, UserManager that I got from `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();`
- I do the same thing with the respective Role (-> authRole), both of these are found and I can see their values in the debugger.
- User doesn't have the role yet, so I execute ´await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, authRole.Id);`... and get an exception:

...

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The Role "50ab556b-a8e4-4294-b91c-1f9374c25244" does not exist at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<AddToRoleAsync>d__3b.MoveNext()
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Is it the fact that I'm using a WebAPI Controller instead of regular? Maybe because I use HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() instead of HttpContext.GetOwinContext() to load the User/Role Manager? But if there's something wrong with Role-/Usermanager ... how does it find the user and the role when I search for it, only when I try to add the user to the role it doesn't work? AddToRoleAsync is the very same method I used just today, when I registered my TestUsers to add the role "NewUser" to them ...

Comment: why don't you pass userId as a parameter in http request and add ID as a parameter into your WebApi Controller? Also, why do you throw an exception if user == null and catch it? Isn't it easier to return BadRequest instead of describing this logic at exception handler?

Comment: Also to understand what's going on add please UserManager.AddToRoleAsync() method body since this is the place you are getting exception from

Comment: You are swapping between role and authRole part way through your code. I can't see where authRole is defined.

Comment: @OlegI : It's predefined in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core . All I know is `public virtual Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(TKey userId, string role);`.

Comment: @RobAnthony : ah sorry, I removed some unnecessary debug code for this post, must've removed it as well. 
`var authRole = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync("AuthorizedUser");`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was using role.id instead of role.Name in AddToRoleAsync .... -___-